# Which CPU increments the jiffies in SMP?

Tags: timer, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

As I read, the jiffies is incremented on every timer tick by the timer ISR.  But in SMP, all CPUs will have their own timer interrupt and hence their own timer ISRs. So my question is:

Is jiffies global across all CPUs? If so, how and which CPU increments it in its timer ISR?

As per my understanding the jiffies can not be per CPU otherwise the same process when scheduled on different CPU will see different jiffy value.

Answer (score 6):

There are two timer interrupts:
The local timer interrupt (`LOC` in `/proc/interrupts`) fires once per jiffy on each CPU.
The global timer interrupts (interrupt 0) fires once per jiffy, on any CPU. It increments `jiffies`.

Note that the "Tickless Kernel" configuration option (introduced in Linux 2.6.21, `CONFIG_NO_HZ`), removes these interrupts. With a tickless kernel, there's no periodic interrupt any more. Instead, when a process starts its quantum, Linux sets an "alarm clock" in the hardware to trigger an interrupt when the quantum is over.

Comment: CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
  0:         41         19          0          8   IO-APIC-edge      timer  
@ugoren: Above is the output of cat /proc/interrupts for interrupt 0 on my ubuntu desktop. I still wonder which CPU is calculating jiffies on which timer interrupt. Below is my cat /proc/version  Linux version 3.2.0-26-generic-pae (buildd@lamiak) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) )

Comment: Looks like the global timer interrupt is handled by a different CPU each time. I see no problem with it.

Comment: Yes the global timer (interrupt 0) is being handled by a different CPU each time. But if this timer increments the jiffies then the sum of count on all the CPUs should be jiffies values. But the sum is 68( 41 + 19 + 0 + 8) which can not be jiffies.

Comment: I guess you're using a tick-less kernel. I'll update the answer a little.

Answer (score 0):

See this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32819011/is-do-timer-supposed-to-be-called-on-only-one-core-in-smp-systems).

Basically, `tick_do_timer_cpu` variable holds CPU ID which is supposed to run code which manages jiffies. The jiffies management function execution can jump from one core to the another, but update cannot be done on different cores in the same time obviously.

See also [`kernel/time/tick-common.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/tick-common.c#L79)