# Is do_timer() supposed to be called on only one core in SMP systems?

Tags: linux-kernel

I understand that do_timer is responsible for updating jiffies counter. Therefore my question, can it be executed on different cores or always on the same core on which the timer tick occurred?

Comment: According to `do_timer` implementation, it updates `jiffies_64`, which is global variable (not per-CPU one). So, it has no restriction to single-core CPU systems.

Comment: Indeed it's global and not per CPU variable, but if you look from a wider context do_timer() is called always on one cpu. On which one it's stored in  tick_do_timer_cpu variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me answer my own question after googling and reading code.

[`do_timer()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c#L1915) is supposed to be called on cpu with ID kept in [`tick_do_timer_cpu`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/tick-common.c#L39) variable.

`kernel/time/tick-common.c`

> /*
>   * tick_do_timer_cpu is a timer core internal variable which holds the CPU NR
>   * which is responsible for calling do_timer(), i.e. the timekeeping stuff.This
>   * variable has two functions:
>   *
>   * 1) Prevent a thundering herd issue of a gazillion of CPUs trying to grab the
>   *    timekeeping lock all at once. Only the CPU which is assigned to do the
>   *    update is handling it.
>   *
>   * 2) Hand off the duty in the NOHZ idle case by setting the value to
>   *    TICK_DO_TIMER_NONE, i.e. a non existing CPU. So the next cpu which looks
>   *    at it will take over and keep the time keeping alive.  The handover
>   *    procedure also covers cpu hotplug.
>   */

`tick_do_timer_cpu` is checked against current CPU ID in [`tick_periodic()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/tick-common.c#L79) or in [`tick_sched_do_timer()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/tick-sched.c#L112). If current CPU is the same `do_timer()` is called otherwise not.

```
static void tick_periodic(int cpu)
 {
      if (tick_do_timer_cpu == cpu) {
              write_seqlock(&jiffies_lock);

              /* Keep track of the next tick event */
              tick_next_period = ktime_add(tick_next_period, tick_period);

              do_timer(1);
              write_sequnlock(&jiffies_lock);
              update_wall_time();
      }

      update_process_times(user_mode(get_irq_regs()));
      profile_tick(CPU_PROFILING);
  }`
```

This way jiffies management is done on one core in SMP systems.